# Invocar una función de JS, escrita en un archivo, por consola

Tags: javascript, html, function

Quiero crear una `funcion` en un archivo `js` que se muestre por la `consola`. La `función` debe tomar el valor e imprimirlo.

Actualmente, hice esto en el archivo `js`:

```
function saludo (prueba){

console.log('Hola ' + prueba);

}
```

Pero en la `consola` sale esto:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: saludo is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna solución?

El html completo es solo esto:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hola Mundo</html>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="holaMundo.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Y esta es la carpeta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @Franqo, la razón por la que presentas ese error es porque llamas la función sin el parámetro. Por ejemplo, la llamas como `saludo();` en lugar de `saludo("alguna cadena");`. Al llamarla sin el parámetro en la consola te devolverá el resultado como indefinido.

Comment: Pues, hice eso pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error @DavidE.LunaM.

Comment: Básicamente, lo que quiero es crear la función en js y pasarle valores desde la consola @BetaM

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo, se me pasó por alto que la estabas llamando como `saludo(Franco)`. En ese caso, estás haciendo referencia a una variable que no has definido. Debes definirla primero y luego llamar la función. Es decir, `let Franco = "Alguna cadena"` y luego `saludo(Franco)` para que no te devuelva `undefined`.

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo, revisa mi respuesta. Allí se incorporaron unos _Snippet_ como ejemplo. El primero con el error y el segundo corregido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes un error al cerrar la etiqueta `<title>`

Fíjate que el título de la web es: `"Hola mundo </html><script>...`" y evidentemente esto nos dice que el título no está bien cerrado, en vez de un "`</title>`" usaste un "`</html>`" de manera que el navegador entiende que la página termino, así que no continua cargando.
Así que, efectivamente no conoce la función "`saludo()`".

Por cierto, el parámetro que le indiques en la consola debería contener un string, así que en vez de `saludo(Franco)` deberías poner `saludo("Franco")`.

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo Esta es la respuesta buena

Comment: Lo mismo pense @ordago +1. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que puedo ver el problema que tienes ahí sucede ya que tu función "saludo" recibe un dato llamado "prueba" el cual no esta definido. Para que todo funcione debes definir "prueba" antes.

Comment: Pues no funciona pasándole el valor, si miras la imagen escribo `saludo(franco);` y sale el error mencionado. Del mismo modo, si escribo `saludo('franco');` sale el mismo error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: saludo is not defined at <anonymous>:1:1`

Comment: Si porque el dato "Franco" no esta definido, si lo generaras al dato "Prueba" a través de una variable o constante que se encuentre bacía y luego la modificaras atrevas de la consola. 
Pero tendrías que hacer tu console.log se efectuara cuando la variable "prueba" === String(eso lo podrías realizar a través de un if).
Lo que te estoy diciendo lo voy pensando muy sobre la marcha espero haberte sido de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

## Observaciones

De acuerdo a lo que pude observar en tu función:

```js
function saludo (prueba){
  console.log('Hola ' + prueba);
}
```

Cuando la estabas llamando lo hacías así:

```js
function saludo (prueba) {
  console.log('Hola ' + prueba);
}

saludo(Franco);
```

Dando como resultado `ReferenceError: Franco is not defined`. Esto se corrige realizando el siguiente cambio:

```js
let Franco = "Alguna cadena";

function saludo(prueba) {
  console.log('Hola ' + prueba);
}

saludo(Franco);
```

Ya que la variable `Franco` que estabas pasando como parámetro de la `saludo()` no estaba definida.

Comment: Si, pero todo esto funciona escribiendo la función en la consola y lo que yo quiero es no escribirla en la consola. Quiero que esté en el js y en la consola escribirr unicamente saludo("Ejemplo");

Comment: Es que cuando la invoco sale ese error, ese es el problema. En mi archivo `js` tengo `function saludo(prueba) {   console.log('Hola ' + prueba); }` y lo llamo desde `html` así: `<script type="text/javascript" src="holaMundo.js"></script>` pero cuando en la consola escribo: `saludo("Comunidad");` sale el error: que les he comentado @BetaM

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo, de acuerdo a lo que me explicas, en el `js` deberías tener declarada la variable antes de pasarla como parámetro. Pero, si llamas la función como `saludo("Algo de texto");` no debería presentar errores.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres prueba de esta forma, saludos!

```js
// SI quisieras que el nombre  este definido 
var Prueba = "Juan"

if(Prueba === "Juan"){
    console.log('Hola ' + Prueba);
}

// Si no quieres que Prueba(nombre este definido)

var Prueba = "";

if(Prueba === String){
    console.log('Hola' + Prueba);
}
```

Comment: Tienes razón, muchas gracias!